# Is there any way to start/stop flurry at runtime?

Tags: ios, iphone, flurry

I want to provide an option to user in my iOS app to start or stop flurry logging at runtime.

Is there any way to end the flurry session at run time? I didn't find any such method in flurry API.

Answer (score 0):

Use a global variable or preference to store user's decision to log or not. Then for each flurry logging event, check the variable/preference first.

Comment: Cant we use setEventLoggingEnabled: method.

Answer (score 0):

This method from Flurry API will help you to achieve your output

```
+ (void)setEventLoggingEnabled:(BOOL)value;
```

you can pass "YES/TRUE" OR "NO/FALSE" you can use this with UISwitch so that user can enable and disable the state at runtime.

Answer (score 0):

Looking for the same thing and found these:

```
[Flurry setEventLoggingEnabled:false];
[Flurry setSessionReportsOnCloseEnabled:false];
[Flurry setSessionReportsOnPauseEnabled:false];
```

Which helped me to stop flurry on runtime.

Starting (on runtime) should be:

```
[Flurry setEventLoggingEnabled:true];
[Flurry setSessionReportsOnCloseEnabled:true];
[Flurry setSessionReportsOnPauseEnabled:true];
```

Remember when starting on a cold start that you don't do StartSession(), this will cause calls to the API.

But when I contacted Flurry about this they replied with the following:

> I would suggest having branches within the app for your offline mode
>   and do not initialize the Flurry session or report events within those
>   branches. Something similar to this:

```
//dont start a Flurry session if the evironment is offline mode
If (env != offline)
[Flurry startSession:@"KEYKEY" withOptions:launchOptions];

//dont log an event if the environment is offline mode
If (env != offline)
[Flurry logEvent:@"Article_Read"];
```

Answer (score 0):

Since setEventLoggingEnabled is deprecated, there is no way to stop Flurry at runtime as of version 7.9 onwards.